# How can I get a file word count while excluding a time stamp such as [00:00:00] in unix?

Tags: unix, text-files, word-count

I have a text file that appears with the file name and on the next line a timestamp and the text as seen below.

```
1234.wma
[00:00:00] this is where the text I want to count is.
```

I used `sed 1,1d test.txt | wc test.txt` to ignore the first line, but the word count is off due to the time stamp. How can I get it to ignore the time stamp in the file?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sed '1d;s/^\[[0-9:]*\]//g' < test.txt | wc -l
```

You can run  multiple sed statement separated by `;`